# Transposing Specifc Column to Row Headers and Count, then order by Division

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, rows, transpose

I really, really need your help with this,

I'd like to have an SQL query that I could run using MS Access/ADO Jet 4.0 that would take the data from the top table (which is a working example of what is the current data structure in the MDB file) and produce the resulting metrics table in the 2nd table depicted below thus Transposing the [Request Type] Column to Row Headers and Count, then order by Division.

This seems like advanced SQL algebra to me, and goes far beyond my level of SQL knowledge/programming.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need query like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Table1.[Division]) AS CountOfDivision
SELECT Table1.[Branch], Table1.Division
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Branch], Table1.Division
PIVOT Table1.[RequestType];
```